# How to pass the first object from an array to a variable in Vue.js?

Tags: vue.js

I have a computed property which is an array of objects from an api.
I use a variable to show these objects on the page. How can I set first object in the variable on page load?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Use a computed property for accessing the first array element via it's index:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data () {
    return {
      items: []
    }
  },
  mounted () {
    // simulate an async api call
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.items = Array.from(Array(10), (x,i) => {
        return {
          id: i + 1,
          text: `Item ${i + 1}`
        }
      })
    }, 2500)
  },
  computed: {
    item () {
      return !!this.items.length ? this.items[0] : null
    }
  }
})
```

```css
/* loading dots */

* {
  background-color: rgba(129,212,250,1);
}

.loading:after {
  content: ' .';
  animation: dots 1s steps(5, end) infinite;}

@keyframes dots {
  0%, 20% {
    color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
    text-shadow:
      .25em 0 0 rgba(0,0,0,0),
      .5em 0 0 rgba(0,0,0,0);}
  40% {
    color: black;
    text-shadow:
      .25em 0 0 rgba(0,0,0,0),
      .5em 0 0 rgba(0,0,0,0);}
  60% {
    text-shadow:
      .25em 0 0 black,
      .5em 0 0 rgba(0,0,0,0);}
  80%, 100% {
    text-shadow:
      .25em 0 0 black,
      .5em 0 0 black;}}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div v-if="item">
    <p>ID: {{ item.id }}</p>
    <p>Text: {{ item.text }}</p>
  </div>
  <p class="loading" v-else>Loading</p>
</div>
```

Comment: I tried but I get this error message: Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'acf' of undefined"